# Average values in two consecutive values

Tags: sas, syntax-error, sas-macro

I have the following code in a macro:
...

```
data HE2update (drop=sum_values n_values);
    set dst_end_update;
    by short_date HE;

    %if HE=2 or 3 %then %do;
        sum_values+value;
        n_values+1;

        %if HE=2 %then delete;
            %else %if HE=3 %then %do;
            value = round(sum_values/n_values);
            HE=2;
            %end;
    %end;
    %if HE>3 %then HE=HE-1;
        %else HE;
run;
```

I am getting the following Error: ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, ><, >=, AND, EQ, GE, GT, IN,
LE, LT, MAX, MIN, NE, NG, NL, NOTIN, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.

The error seems to be with the last if/then/else statement I don't see what I need to correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need macro logic here at all.

```
data HE2update (drop=sum_values n_values);
    set dst_end_update;
    by short_date HE;

    if HE in (2, 3) then do;
        sum_values+value;
        n_values+1;

        if HE=2 then delete;
            else if HE=3 then do;
            value = round(sum_values/n_values);
            HE=2;
            end;
    end;
    if HE>3 then HE=HE-1;

run;
```

Comment: Thank you! Sanity restored.

Answer (score 1):

The macro processor is used to generate code, not operate on data.

Your first %IF is testing whether the string `HE` is equal to `2` (which is false) and then OR ing the result with the number `3` (which is true) so the test is true which means these two statements are generated to include in your data step.

```
    sum_values+value;
    n_values+1;
```

The other two %IF tests in that %IF/%THEN/%DO/%END block are both false since the string `HE` does not equal either the digit `2` or the digit `3`.

Then finally you test if the string `HE` is larger than the digit `3` which is TRUE since `H` is after `3` in the ASCII collating sequence.  This means your program will generate the code

```
HE=HE-1
```

Notice that there is no closing semi-colon for that assignment statement.  The semi-colon in the program marks the end of the %IF/%THEN statement.

So the code you generated is:

```
 data HE2update (drop=sum_values n_values);
 set dst_end_update;
 by short_date HE;
 sum_values+value;
 n_values+1;
 HE=HE-1 run;
```

That last assignment statement is not valid SAS syntax. Plus there is no `RUN;` to end the data step.